# Selecting an option from a dropdown in a url

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to select the first option of the dropdown by using the vba function getElementById, but not able to proceed further as I get run time error. Below is the code which I have found through internet and made some changes to it.

```
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
    Dim oElement As HTMLUListElement
    Dim dados As HTMLSelectElement
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As String

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False          ' Keep this hidden.

    IE.Navigate sSiteName



Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

Set dados = oHtml.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue")
dados.Focus
dados.selectedIndex = 1
dados.FireEvent "onchange"
```

This is the HTML code screenshot:
[image]

Comment: That doesnt look like a `dropdown` field. It looks more like a text field within a `Table`. I suspect that is the reason why you are getting the **runtime error**. What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Zac, Thanks for responding to my question. I am getting run-time error 91, object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: You haven't set `oHtml` to point to the document. You've just created a new document. do that by: `Set oHtml = IE.Document` and then try it. Also, after navigating to the URL, you will have to add a wait until browser is ready before setting `oHtml`

Comment: It didn't work. I am getting a different error now. I tried replacing the name of the element by putting the table name as well, but no luck.

Comment: You would because you have now set the `oHtml` object. Previously it was complaining because although `oHtml` was a HTML doc object but was not pointing to anything. What is the new error msg?